# Developer survey 2023: IDEs for programming languages

Tags: discussion, survey

I wonder whether it is possible to find out something like:

"Which IDEs are used by Java programmers (or for Java programming)?"

Sure, this cannot be perfectly done from the data because someone might tick Java and JavaScript as programming languages and tick Eclipse and Visual Studio Code for IDEs, so you don't know what exactly he/she uses Eclipse for, but nevertheless it would be great to see the data either

- filtered by people who ticked Java
- or some correlation between programming language and IDE

Can this be done?

Comment: Once the [raw data is made public](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/) you can slice it any way you want.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it seems absurdly low-value and high-noise for Stack Overflow to undertake and answer now just because you are curious, and easy to do yourself once the data is available.

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to ask an employee to filter data for me, I just thought there might be already an online tool or something similar that allows me to filter the data.

Comment: For the 2022 data, something like this? https://replit.com/@tripleee/java-ide-2022#main.py

Comment: @tripleee That looks like a good start.